# Link to an item on a paginated page in php

Tags: php, hyperlink, pagination, anchor

I'm quite a novice coder in PHP / MySQL. I am developing a site at the moment and have found many answers to some of the questions I have had on this site - Great Resource! - but now I need to ask one of my own which I'm struggling with. Do bear with me...

So on my site I have a side panel which shows testimonials from a database and randomly pulls in 1 result so that the testimonial showing changes every time the user navigates around the site. The side panel is an php include and is shown across the site. I am only showing a few lines of the testimonial and then including a read more link.

On the testimonials page, I have 13 testimonials paginated on 1 per page (13 pages) as each testimonial is quite long - that's how the client wants it.

What I am looking to do is to link from the 'Read More' link to the relevant testimonial - I assume using an html anchor is best? The issue I'm finding is that I can't seem to link to the relevant item on it's paginated page. If I use the testimonial ID I can link through to only page 1 of the testimonials.php and not to the specific page that the testimonial appears on. I hope this makes sense?

I have included a copy of my code from the Side Panel and also on the Testimonial page.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Sidebar.php**

```
$gettest = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM testimonial ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($gettest)) 
{
$testimonial = $row['testimonial'];
$shorttest = myTruncate($testimonial, 200, " ");
?>

<blockquote><span class="bqstart">&#8220;</span><p><?PHP echo $shorttest;?></p><span class="bqend">&#8221;</span></blockquote>      
<p><a href="testimonials.php#<?PHP echo '' . $row["id"] . '';?>"><?PHP echo '' . $row["name"] . '';?></a></p>
<br clear='all' />

<?PHP
}                           
mysql_close($DB);
?>
```

**Testimonials.php**

```
<?php

include('connectDB.php'); 

$tableName="testimonial";
$targetpage = "testimonials.php";
$limit = 1; 

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM testimonial";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$stages = 3;
$page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);
if($page){
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
}else{
$start = 0;
}   

// Get page data
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM testimonial LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query1);

// Initial page num setup
if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);
$LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    

$paginate = '';
if($lastpage > 1)
{   

$paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
// Previous
if ($page > 1){
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
}else{
$paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }

// Pages
if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))  // Not enough pages to breaking it up
{
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page){
 $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
}else{
 $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}
}
}
elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))   // Enough pages to hide a few?
{

// Beginning only hide later pages
if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))
{
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
{
 if ($counter == $page){
     $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
 }else{
     $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}
}
$paginate.= "...";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
}

// Middle hide some front and some back
elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
$paginate.= "...";
for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
{
 if ($counter == $page){
     $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
 }else{
     $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}
}
$paginate.= "...";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
}

// End only hide early pages
else
{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
$paginate.= "...";
for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
{
 if ($counter == $page){
     $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
 }else{
     $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}
}
}           

}

// Next
if ($page < $counter - 1){
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
}else{
$paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
}

$paginate.= "</div>";       

}
// pagination
echo $paginate;

?>



<?php 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{



?>
<a name="<?PHP echo '' . $row["ID"] . '';?>"></a>

<blockquote><span class="bqstart">&#8220;</span><p><?PHP echo '' .nl2br($row["testimonial"]) . '';?></p><span class="bqend">&#8221;</span></blockquote> 
<p class="highlight"><?PHP echo '' . $row["name"] . '';?></p>
<br clear='all' />

<?PHP
}

echo $paginate;

mysql_close($DB);

?>
```

Comment: Can you not just make the page id the 'testimonial id'? That way, the testimonials.php page just shows the testimonial for that id, and you can still have the pagination on the page.

Comment: Thanks gmadd. Any pointers as to how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to to go into all the changes you can do to your code, because right now it's messy.

You probably went lost in your own code.

Just change this line (on the sidebar.php), to:

```
<p><a href="testimonials.php?page=<?PHP echo '' . $row["id"] . '';?>"><?PHP echo '' . $row["name"] . '';?></a></p>
```

(similar to what you've already done on your "Testimonials.php" page.)

Comment: Thanks Hanan. Appreciate the feedback. As I say, I'm not the best of coders. Wondered if you could point out what is wrong with the code and how to make it better? Thanks

Comment: It's ok, we all began somewhere.
It's not wrong, but you can do it more efficiently.
Try reading about classes and objects.
it will make your code less crowded. :)

Comment: Thanks very much Hanan. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Somethis like this:

```
<?php
$gettest = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM testimonial ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($gettest)) 
{
$testimonial = $row['testimonial'];
$shorttest = myTruncate($testimonial, 200, " ");
?>

<blockquote><span class="bqstart">&#8220;</span><p><?PHP echo $shorttest;?></p><span class="bqend">&#8221;</span></blockquote>      
<p><a href="testimonials.php?testimonialid=<?PHP echo '' . $row["id"] . '';?>"><?PHP echo '' . $row["name"] . '';?></a></p>
<br clear='all' />

<?PHP
}                           
mysql_close($DB);
?>
```

and

```
<?php
include('connectDB.php'); 

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM testimonial";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$testimonialid = mysql_escape_string($_GET['testimonialid']);  

// Get page data
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM testimonial WHERE id = ".$testimonialid;
$result = mysql_query($query1);

$paginate = '';
if($total_pages > $testimonialid)
{
    $paginate .= '<a href="testimonials.php?testimonialid='.($testimonialid+1).'">next</a>';
}
if($testimonialid > 1)
{
    $paginate .= '<a href="testimonials.php?testimonialid='.($testimonialid-1).'">previous</a>';
}
?>



<?php
echo $paginate;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    ?>
    <a name="<?PHP echo '' . $row["ID"] . '';?>"></a>

    <blockquote><span class="bqstart">&#8220;</span><p><?PHP echo '' .nl2br($row["testimonial"]) . '';?></p><span class="bqend">&#8221;</span></blockquote> 
    <p class="highlight"><?PHP echo '' . $row["name"] . '';?></p>
    <br clear='all' />

    <?php
}

echo $paginate;

mysql_close($DB);
?>
```

I've removed most of the pagination code, but that's just to show you how it can be achieved a little simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much gmadd. Kind of you to show me how to improve it.